# How to standardize the number of characters in a column?

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a column (in my data-file database) where the number of characters is not standardized, and need to standardize. How can I do it?

Example:

```
Sample_ID
159
148
1110
1100
150
```

But my bank does not run that way, I need to have a bank of this type:

```
Sample_ID
0159
0148
1110
1100
0150
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Is the required output always 4 digits, or does the maximum width need to be determined from the file?

Comment: Are all lines between 3 and 4 numbers? is only the first line different? What tools (programs) do you use? Is it enough to assume that data like the above is in a text file and needs to be saved to another text file after processing? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I required always the maximum width to be determined. Because I will need transforms the other columm of my file too. @steeldriver

Comment: @Lucas I have other columm with different character number. My file have 400 lines. I'm using the function of Linux (awk) to edite my file, because before I will use BLUPF90 (genetic software).

Comment: I get com standardize with space, using :  awk –F”:” ‘ NR==1, NR==10{printf “%-8s %3d\n”, $1,$3 } ‘ file.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the datafile with any of several scripting languages.  With `awk`,

```
awk '/^[0-9]+$/ { printf "%04d\n", $0; next; } { print; }' < oldfile >newfile
```

Similarly, you can format numbers with leading zeros using `printf` in bash, zsh, etc.

Comment: Thank you! But I didn't get the results. I put this way:                                              awk '/^[0-9]+$/ { printf "%04d\n", $1; next; } { print; "$2" " " "$3" }' oldfile >newfile                                                               And the newfile was same the oldfile.